# How to set up my urls with posts/1, posts/2, etc?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm following a few of the basic django blog tutorials.  The part I am stuck on is how to set variables in my urls.

I want my urls to look like:

```
posts/1
posts/2
posts/3
```

Currently when i visit my index.html i see the list of blog posts (just the titles), and when I hover the cursor over each link it does show posts/1, posts/2, etc.

The problem is that when I click on these links, it basically just refreshes the page and does not show the detailed view.

my urls.py currently looks like this:

```
url(r'^posts/', index),
url(r'^posts/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', detailedview),
```

I'm not sure exactly what (?P[0-9]+)/$', does and I'm assuming this is the problem because detailedview is never being called.

This method is inside my views.py but again, it is never being called.

```
def detailedview(request, post_id):
    targetpost = Post.objects.get(id="post_id")
    context = {'targetpost': targetpost}
    return render(request, 'posts/detailedview.html', context)
```

Comment: You really need to go through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/).

Comment: I am.  This exercise is taken directly from the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question about the second URL:

`(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)` is a regex that means "set the post_id argument to the value of any number with one or more digits (more info at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html.)

The way to fix your problem is to add a `$` to the end of the first pattern, so it looks like this:

```
url(r'^posts/$', index),
```

This will make it only match the URL `/posts/`.

There is also a problem with your view: the line

```
    targetpost = Post.objects.get(id="post_id")
```

should be:

```
    targetpost = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
```

This will make Django look for the `Post` with the `id` specified in the variable `post_id`, rather than the `Post` with the `id` that equals the string `"post_id"`

Comment: Thank you, I never knew what the $ signified, very good to know.

Comment: If you want to learn more about regular expressions, go to the the [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) link on the python documentation page, which shows you everything you can add to a regular expression like those in the URLconf.